# No ConcurrentModificationException while looping using foreach

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to run the below code:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("jim");
l.add("pam");

for(String s : l) {
    l.remove(s);
}
```

But I am not getting any exception. Isn't the for each loop uses Iterator and we cannot change the structure of the List while iterating?

EDIT:

I am getting the `ConcurrentModificationException`when the list has 3+ elements.Why is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` is because your list only has two elements which prevents the implementation from detecting the concurrent modification. Here's the Java 13 `Iterator` implementation used by `ArrayList`:

> ```
> private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
>     int cursor;       // index of next element to return
>     int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
>     int expectedModCount = modCount;
>
>     // prevent creating a synthetic constructor
>     Itr() {}
>
>     public boolean hasNext() {
>         return cursor != size;
>     }
>
>     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
>     public E next() {
>         checkForComodification();
>         int i = cursor;
>         if (i >= size)
>             throw new NoSuchElementException();
>         Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
>         if (i >= elementData.length)
>             throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
>         cursor = i + 1;
>         return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
>     }
>
>     public void remove() {
>         if (lastRet < 0)
>             throw new IllegalStateException();
>         checkForComodification();
>
>         try {
>             ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
>             cursor = lastRet;
>             lastRet = -1;
>             expectedModCount = modCount;
>         } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
>             throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
>         }
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
>         Objects.requireNonNull(action);
>         final int size = ArrayList.this.size;
>         int i = cursor;
>         if (i < size) {
>             final Object[] es = elementData;
>             if (i >= es.length)
>                 throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
>             for (; i < size && modCount == expectedModCount; i++)
>                 action.accept(elementAt(es, i));
>             // update once at end to reduce heap write traffic
>             cursor = i;
>             lastRet = i - 1;
>             checkForComodification();
>         }
>     }
>
>     final void checkForComodification() {
>         if (modCount != expectedModCount)
>             throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
>     }
> }
> ```

As you can see, it checks for concurrent modification in the `next()` method, but not in the `hasNext()` method. This is important. If you aren't aware, enhanced for loops use `Iterator`s behind the scenes. In other words, your for-each loop is equivalent to:

```java
for (Iterator<String> itr = l.itr(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    String e = itr.next();
    l.remove(e);
}
```

Once your loop removes the first element there's only one element left in the list. However, that element has moved down an index (1 → 0) but the cursor of the iterator has been incremented by one. This makes the cursor equal to the size and thus the loop **does not execute a second time**. Since the loop doesn't execute a second time the `next()` method isn't called again and the check for concurrent modification doesn't occur. This also has the side-effect of leaving the second element in the list.

Once your list has three or more elements the loop *does* execute a second time which allows it to detect the concurrent modification.